# How to use ADWIN with multiple columns

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to perform drift detection on data with multiple input values (x0, x1, x2, x3). I'm using an adaptive window algorithm found from `sci-kit` found [here](https://scikit-multiflow.github.io/scikit-multiflow/_autosummary/skmultiflow.drift_detection.ADWIN.html).

Doing this

```py
from skmultiflow.drift_detection.adwin import ADWIN
adwin = ADWIN()
adwin.add_element(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Results in `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

But doing this

```py
from skmultiflow.drift_detection.adwin import ADWIN
adwin = ADWIN()
adwin.add_element(np.array([1])
```

works just fine.

Any idea how to do the first thing?

My current solution is to just use 4 different drift detectors, but I would like to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently implemented. So while you can add any number as a concept value, you're probably best served by adding 1s and 0s depending on whether a not misspecification occurred.

The reason it is not implemented is probably that ADWIN essentially performs a statistical test (or a heuristic approximation) whether the mean of two (large enough) windows is significantly different. And comparison of multivariate mean vectors is very tricky, in particular if one cannot make any assumptions about normality etc.

Otherwise, your workaround of using 4 drift detectors seems like the best solution!

Comment: "_... adding 1s and 0s depending on whether a not misspecification occurred_"   
  
Could you explain what you mean by this and what you mean by "concept value"?

Comment: Often you want to track shifts in the error rate of your classification scheme or something similar. By adding 1s and 0s for (mis)classifications you can do just that.